# setInterval double times on occasion

Tags: javascript

I've made a slideshow script with JQuery and I'm using setInterval (I tried with setTimeout also and got the same issue). The problem is when I go to a new tab and come back to my page with the slideshow on it the slideshow seems to be going at double speed. Some times it even slows down and gets back to normal speed. I'm quite confused as to why it does this. Please note I have only tried this in FF at this time.

```
pictureAmount = 4;
fadeSpeed = 600;
delay = 6000;
heightOfPicture = 320; //px

function nextSlide(count) {
    $('#slide-link').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, 'linear', function () {
        document.getElementById('slide-link').style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (heightOfPicture * count) + 'px';
    }).fadeIn(fadeSpeed, 'linear');
}

count = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (++count >= pictureAmount) count = 0;

    nextSlide(count);
}, delay);
```

Here is the link http://mprodesigns.com/new

Comment: I tried this on Windows/FF5 and it run with the same speed. Did you try this from another browser/OS/computer?

Comment: I'm using win7 and FF5 as well. I don't know why it's double speeding for me then if yours seems normal. Maybe stay on the new tab for a minute or 2? I noticed it when I went to check my FB and then came back to work on it

Answer (score 7):

What you're seeing is a common (and fairly new) behavior in updated browsers. They slow down your timers when pages are inactive. When you get back to the page, the timer "catches up".

It helps to just avoid "setInterval()" entirely and use "setTimeout()" instead. Have your own code re-set the timeout on each wakeup.  That way, you won't have lots of pending handler invocations to run.

So instead of "setInterval()" you can do this:

```
function timerHandler() {
  if (++count >= pictureAmount) count = 0;
  nextSlide(count);
  setTimeout(timerHandler, delay);
}

setTimeout(timerHandler, delay);
```

The "slow down" effect is imposed by upping the minimum delay time. Normally, when you have focus on the window, it's like 10 or 15 milliseconds. When the tab/window is not focused, however, it's like 1000 milliseconds.

*edit* — [Here is a demonstration page](http://jsfiddle.net/eHU2M/) which should not show an anomalous speed-up if you leave the tab and return to it.

Comment: Oh, so this is completely unavoidable or is there a way to check for these events?

Comment: You can't keep the browsers from doing it, but you can mitigate the problem. I'll add to my answer - give me a sec.

Comment: Ok so how do I know when the page is sleeping?

Comment: You can track "mouseleave" if you need to, or else you can just use "setTimeout()" instead of "setInterval()".

Comment: It does, sort-of, but there should only be one cycle that runs fast - is that not so?  I'll set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: I see... I've made the exact same changes you have there but for some reason it still tries to catch up