# jquery - add multiple timers associated to HTML divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I have the following `DIV` containing multiple `cards` elements:

[image]

Each of those `cards` have the following `HTML` structure:

```
<div class="user-w">
                        <div class="avatar with-status status-green">
                          <img alt="" src="img/avatar1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                          <div class="user-date">
                            12 min
                          </div>
                          <div class="user-name">
                            John Mayers
                          </div>
                          <div class="last-message">
                            What is going on, are we...
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Those `cards` are loaded dynamically using `ajax`. What I need is to attach to each `<div class="user-w">` a stopwatch so I can change for example background color when elapsed time is 4 min or make it hidden when elapsed time reaches 6 min.

I was thinking on using `SetInterval` multiple times for I think this is not possible.

Each `DIV` card element should be totally independant in terms of timing from the others.

> Any clue on how to do it correctly?

Comment: When you say `4min` and `6min` is it from the time the AJAX call completed? Or does it have anything to do with the time values in the card?

Comment: Has to do with the time values in the card, that value comes from the ajax json object. So lets say first card have 3 min in the json, so now I have to dipslay the DIV in my DOM and start the stopwatch.

Comment: In your ajax function are you replacing all cards or appending new cards to the list of cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, shy away from the "attach everywhere" syndrome.  Think in lists, and simple processors.  You will thank yourself down the road, as will your users for more efficient code, and your maintenance programmer.

Accordingly, one thought process might be to setup an array of the elements in question, and use a single `setInterval`.  Something like:

```
...
var cardList = [];

function processCards ( ) {
    var i, cardEl, cardStartTime, now;

    now = Date.now();
    i = -1;
    while ( ++i < cardList.length ) {
        cardEl = cardList[ i ][ 0 ];
        cardStartTime = cardList[ i ][ 1 ];
        if ( cardStartTime + 6 min < now ) {
            // do 6 minute thing
        }
        else if ( cardStartTime + 4 min < now ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

$.get('/your/new/cards/call')
.done(function(...){
    ...
    var now = Date.now();
    for ( i in returnedCards ) {
        cardElement = however_you_create_your_element;
        attach cardElement to the DOM

        // save reference to element and time created for later processing
        cardList.push([cardElement, now]);
    }

});

setInterval(processCards, 2*60*1000); // or whatever granularity you want.
```

One advantage of this approach over multiple `setTimeout` calls for each card is the simplicity of having a single processing function, rather than N copies lying around.  It's easier to reason about and manage, and reduces the likelihood of errors if an element disappears before it's associated `setTimeout` function executes.

Comment: I like this approach. So if I run the setInterval every 2 seconds, how long does processCards will take if I have lets say 50 cards and im just chaning background color. What happen if processCards takes more than 2 seconds? Another call will be executed while the first one is running?

Comment: With your code can I even still update the minutes badge? Or you recommend me better maybe to have other setInterval function that runs maybe every minute that goes to server and gets all cards elapsed badge values?

Comment: @VAAA `processCards` is unlikely to take 2 seconds unless there are way more than 50 divs

Comment: No.  Webworkers notwithstanding, Javascript in the browser is single-threaded.  Meaning, that no matter how long `processCards` takes, it won't run concurrently with another invocation.  That said, @ChiragRavindra is correct: computers are *fast*.  However, if you're worried about it, just [do the setInterval yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572680/setinterval-double-times-on-occasion).

Comment: @hunteke so what you mean is that is not possible to have 2 setInterval commands calling different fucntions at different intervals?

Comment: @VAAA Regarding updating the minutes badge: yep. The innards of that function are completely up to you.  The point is that you just need a single function to do the card manipulation logic, whatever that may entail.  You don't need (or want) multiple copies of the same logic.

Comment: @hunteke got it :), so in the same function i would update the minutes badge. Nice.

Comment: @VAAA you can have as many `setInterval` timers (with a requisite number of functions) as you like, up to the limits imposed by the interpreter.  However, even if you have all your `setInterval` calls set to exactly the same period (say 10ms for argument's sake), only and exactly one will ever run at a time.  This is the meaning of "single-threaded".

Comment: @VAAA it is possible to `have 2 setInterval commands calling different fucntions at different intervals`. But since JS is single threaded, at any one time, the call stack is executing only one function at a time. If two functions come up for execution at the same time, they are both added to the stack and the one at the top of the stack is executed first and then the next.

Comment: The ajax function never removes items from cardList but may remove them from DOM (OP is not clear about how cards are added)

Answer (score 1):

When you build the card from the ajax object, set a data element to store the timestamp on the card. Use setInterval to trigger a function that loops through all of the cards and checks their timestamps against the current time and updates the date on the ui, changes the bgcolor, or removes the element altogether.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add a function with `setTimeout()` for ajax `success:` parameter.

Ex(with jquery):-

```
    $.ajax({
    // your ajax process
     success:function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
       $('.card-w').not('.anotherclassname').addClass('someclassname-'+i);
       $('someclassname-'+i).addClass('.anotherclassname').fadeOut();
      },6000);
     }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is, after your AJAX call completes and the DOM has been updated, you can use jQuery to select your cards and for each card you can:

1. Get the time value and parse it to convert it to `milliseconds` - you can write a simple helper function for this or use something like `momentjs` based on how complex your requirement is
2. Use `setTimeout` with the parsed value and do any style updates/hiding as needed

Sample Code:

```
$('.user-w').each(function(i, el){
    var $el = $(el);
    var val = $el.find('div.user-date').html();
    val = parseTime(val) // Assuming a function to parse time from string to milliseconds is there
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Do any updates here on $el (this user card)
    }, val);
    /*setTimeout(function(){
        // Do something else when val ms is close to completion
        // here on $el (this user card)
    }, 0.9 * val);*/
})
```

If you want multiple things to happen (change bg color and then, later, hide element, for example) you can set multiple `setTimeout`s to happen with different time values derived from `val`

Comment: Very intersting, i now understand about the single thread on client side. and as you said it doesnt make sense then to have 2 functions running at different time when actually javascript cant run the 2 at the same in case at some point those are triggered simulatniously. I will do it within just 1 setInvertal function then.

Comment: This video on the event loop helped me get my head around how it works on the inside: https://vimeo.com/96425312

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer can give you a lot of trouble if the ajax part

> > however_you_create_your_element;
> >
> > attach cardElement to the DOM

Is replacing or adding elements. Ajax and processCards share cardlist and your ajax may remove items from DOM but leave them in cardlist.

You failed to mention if you replace the card list in your ajax or append new cards but the following solution would work either way.

To adjust to updating every minute and showing minutes you can change the following 2 lines:

```
const repeat = 1000;//repeat every second
const message = timePassed=>`${Math.round(timePassed/1000)} seconds`
```

to:

```
const repeat = 60000;//repeat every minute
const message = timePassed=>`${Math.round(timePassed/60000)} min`
```

```js
(function(){//assuming cardContainer is available
  const container = document.querySelector("#cardContainer");
  const repeat = 1000;//repeat every second
  const message = timePassed=>`${Math.round(timePassed/1000)} seconds`
  const updateCards = function(){
    Array.from(container.querySelectorAll(".user-w .user-date"))
    .map(
      (element)=>{
        var started = element.getAttribute("x-started");
        if(started===null){
          started = Date.now()-
            parseInt(element.innerText.trim().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""),10)*60000;
          element.setAttribute("x-started",started);
        }
        return [
          element,
          Date.now()-parseInt(started,10)
        ];
      }
    ).forEach(
      ([element,timePassed])=>
        element.innerText = message(timePassed)
    );
  }
  setInterval(updateCards,repeat);
}());
```

```html
      <div id="cardContainer">
        <div class="user-w">
            <div class="avatar with-status status-green">
              <img alt="" src="img/avatar1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="user-info">
              <div class="user-date">
                12 min
              </div>
              <div class="user-name">
                John Mayers
              </div>
              <div class="last-message">
                What is going on, are we...
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```